# Probability Question : What is the probability of Attendance of either principal or assistant principal only?

Tags: probability

> Three people are working at a school, namely the principal, the assistant principal, and the secretary. If the probability of attendance of the principal equals the probability of attendance of the assistant principal $=0.9$, and the probability of attendance of the secretary $=0.8$, then what is the probability of attendance of either principal or assistant principal only?

My try:

$$P(P\text{ or }As)=0.9+0.8-(0.9 \cdot 0.8)=0.98$$

Is that okay?

Comment: No.  First... we must make an assumption that the problem did not give us in order to have any chance at proceeding, namely that the attendance of each is *independent* of one another.  This is what allows us to proceed.  Next, you incorrectly interpreted the problem.  letting $P$ be the event that the principal is present, $A$ the event the assistant principal is present, and $S$ that the secretary is present... your calculation is for $Pr(P\cup A)$... the probability that at least one of the principal or assistant principal is present, possibly both, and secretary doesn't matter.

Comment: You also calculated that wrong, having used $0.8$ when you shouldn't have so you accidentally calculated $Pr(P\cup S)$ instead of $Pr(P\cup A)$.  The question however includes the word **only**.  I interpret this to mean that we are interested in the probability $Pr((P\cap A^c\cap S^c)\cup (P^c\cap A\cap S^c))$, i.e. that among the three people, two of them are absent, one of which is present, and the one that is present is either the principal or the assistant principal.

Comment: @JMoravitz  the probability that at least one of the principal or assistant principal is present, possibly both, and secretary doesn't matter.  I think that is the accurate translation of my question since I am not native speaker

Comment: In that case, using my notation above, $Pr(P\cup A) = Pr(P)+Pr(A)-Pr(P\cap A) = 0.9+0.9-\color{red}{0.9\cdot 0.9} = 0.99$ remembering that splitting the intersection apart as a product is only allowed if they are independent events and we had to assume that they were in order to do this.  Without that assumption all we can say is that it is somewhere between $0.9$ and $1$ with each value between possible.

Comment: @JMoravitz thanks very much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Letting $P$ denote the event that the principal attends is potentially confusing since we also use $P(E)$ to denote the probability of an event $E$. So let's let $E_P$ be the event that the principal attends. Let's let $E_A$ be the event that the assistant principal attends, and let's let $E_S$ be the event that the secretary attends.

In your solution, you used the idea that $P(E_P\text{ and }E_A)=P(E_P)\cdot P(E_A)$. Note that this is only true if $E_P$ and $E_A$ are independent. The original post does not mention whether or not these events are independent. Were we given that $E_P$ and $E_A$ are independent? If $E_P$ and $E_A$ are not independent, then we will need additional information to solve this problem.

From here on, let's suppose that $E_P$, $E_A$, and $E_S$ are independent.

In your solution, you used the fact that

$$P(E_A\text{ or }E_P)=P(E_A)+P(E_P)-P(E_P\text{ and }E_A)$$

to calculate $P(E_A\text{ or }E_P)$. Note that "$E_P\text{ or }E_A$" is the event that either $E_P$ happens, or $E_A$ happens, or $E_P$ and $E_A$ both happen. The question in the original post asks for the "probability of attendance of either principal or assistant principal only?" Hence I think the event we are looking for is

$$(E_P\text{ and not }E_A\text{ and not }E_S)\text{ or }(\text{not }E_P\text{ and }E_A\text{ and not }E_S).$$

Let's let $E_1=(E_P\text{ and not }E_A\text{ and not }E_S)$ and let $E_2=(\text{not }E_P\text{ and }E_A\text{ and not }E_S)$.

Note that

$$\begin{align*}
P(E_1) &= P(E_P\text{ and not }E_A\text{ and not }E_S) \\
&= P(E_P)\cdot P(\text{not }E_A)\cdot P(\text{not }E_S) \\
&= 0.9\cdot0.1\cdot0.2 \\
&= 0.018
\end{align*}$$

Similarly

$$\begin{align*}
P(E_2) &= P(\text{not }E_P\text{ and }E_A\text{ and not }E_S) \\
&= P(\text{not }E_P)\cdot P(E_A)\cdot P(\text{not }E_S) \\
&= 0.1\cdot0.9\cdot0.2 \\
&= 0.018
\end{align*}$$

Finally, note that $E_1$ and $E_2$ are mutually exclusive. Hence

$$P(E_1\text{ or }E_2)=P(E_1)+P(E_2)=0.018+0.018=0.036.$$

Comment: Thanks very much for your effort, "the probability that at least one of the principal or assistant principal is present, possibly both, and secretary doesn't matter. I think that is the accurate translation of my question since I am not native speaker

Comment: @user373141 If you want the probability that either the principal attended or the assistant principal attended or they both attended, then you're looking for $P(E_P\text{ or }E_A)$. In your solution, you correctly noted that $P(E_P\text{ or }E_A)=P(E_P)+P(E_A)-P(E_P\text{ and }E_A)$. If $E_P$ and $E_A$ are independent, then we'd have that $P(E_P\text{ or }E_A)=0.9+0.9-(0.9\cdot0.9)=0.99$.

Comment: @user373141 You mentioned that you're not a native speaker of English. I'm terrible at learning languages, and I'm always extremely impressed with anyone who can handle more than one language! Thanks for posting this problem!

Comment: thank you for your beautiful words and for your time and effort answering my questions

Answer (score 1):

$P$(Principal only)$=0.9×0.1×0.2=.018$
since Principal and Assistant principal have eqaul attendance probabilities,
$P$(principal only)$=P$(assistant principal only)$=0.018$

Summing up, the required probability is

$P=0.036$